# Play video immediately in FlowPlayer with buffering?

Tags: html, flash, streaming, flowplayer, buffering

I'm using the FlowPlayer with its HTML5 mode to play mp4 videos. But it seems that the player waits until the chosen video is fully (down)loaded before playing it. I've read that there is a way to buffer/stream a video in the Flash-version of FlowPlayer.
But I don't want to use the flash way because many visitors are using iPhone or iPad. Is there a way to use the standard FlowPlayer to play the videos while downloading the rest of them from the server?

My code currently looks like this:

```
<div class="player" data-engine="flash" style="width: 500px;">
  <video>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="url/to/video/source.mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

Do I have to drop the "data-engine" property?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the HTML5 version of FlowPlayer and want to stick with HTML5 only, get rid of data-engine="flash", or replace it with "html5" (be careful, there's also a full flash version of FlowPlayer).

About the buffering, FlowPlayer loads the video when you click play, but does not wait for the video to be fully loaded. As soon as there are some readable chunks, the video is played.

What you might try is the "preload" attribute (http://flowplayer.org/docs/#video-attributes):

```
<div class="player" style="width: 500px;" preload="true">
  <video>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="url/to/video/source.mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: even with `data-engine="flash"` By default Flowplayer uses the HTML5 video tag and falls back to Flash when HTML5 video is not supported.

Comment: The difference is which one is prior to the other. The rendering engine set in data-engine will be used first, and if it fails, FlowPlayer will fall back to the other one.